# I switched from unity to i3wm but after suspend I still have gnome-screensaver instead of i3lock

Tags: 14.04, unity, suspend, screensaver

How do I configure Ubuntu 14.04 so that when I close the lid of my laptop (in a i3wm session) and open it again, the screen is locked via i3lock instead of gnome-screensaver?

I spent the day searching the configuration files but I could not track down who/when/what is responsible for launching gnome-screensaver at suspend.